# PHP, dropzone.js. Непонятно какой скрипт ограничивает размер загружаемых файлов

Tags: php, apache, dropzone

Проблема при загрузке .txt файлов больше 10МB.
Ранее выдавалось ошибка 500, увеличил php_value post_max_size и php_value upload_max_filesize, проблема с ошибкой 500 решилась, теперь файл загружается полностью но дальше наверное не срабатывает скрипты JS или PHP. Выводится ошибка "Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер. Попробуйте еще раз", которая указан в функции:``

```
public function index()
    {
            if(!empty($_FILES))
            {
                    if(preg_replace("/.*?\./", '',  $_FILES['file']['name'])=='txt')
                    {
                            chmod($this->upload_dir, 0777);

                            $tempFile=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

                            $targetFile=$this->upload_dir . $_FILES['file']['name'];

                            if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile))
                            {
                                    return $this->checkClient($this->DocumentParse($targetFile));
                                    // unlink($targetFile);
                            }
                            else
                                    echo 'Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер. Попробуйте еще раз.';
                    }
                    else
                            echo 'Неверный формат файла';
            }
            else
                    $this->render('checkClient');
    }
     private function checkClient($document_list)
    {
            if(count($document_list))
            {
                    $clients=new Clients;

                    $hash_list=$this->flip($clients->findAll(array(
                            'select'=>'client_id, client_fullname, client_bd, client_passport_series',
                            'condition'=>'client_passport_series=1111111'
                    )));

                    if(count($hash_list))
                    {
                            $update_list=array();

                            foreach($hash_list as $hash=>$item)
                            {
                                    if(isset($document_list[$hash]))
                                            if($document_list[$hash]['client_passport_series']!=$item['client_passport_series'])
                                            {
                                                    $clients->update(array(
                                                            'set'=>'client_passport_series="'.$document_list[$hash]['client_passport_series'].'"',
                                                            'condition'=>'client_id='.$item['client_id'],
                                                    ));
                                                    $update_list[]='Серия паспорта '.$item['client_fullname'].' обновлена с '.$item['client_passport_series'].' до $
                                            }
                            }

                            $this->__pre($update_list);
                     }
                    else
                            return true;
            }
            else
                    return true;
    }
    private function DocumentParse($document)
    {
            $handle=fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
            fwrite($handle, iconv('UCS-2', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($document)));
            rewind($handle);

            $csv_array=array();

            while(($row=fgetcsv($handle, 1000, '    ')) !== false)
            {
                    $client_bd=explode('.', trim($row[1]));
                    $client_passport_series=preg_replace('/[\D]+/ui', '', $row[2]);
                    $client_TIN=(int) trim($row[3]);

                    $csv_array[]=array(
                            'client_fullname'=>trim(preg_replace('/[\s]{2,}/u', ' ', $row[0])),
                            'client_bd'=>count($client_bd)==3 ? (checkdate($client_bd[1], $client_bd[0], $client_bd[2]) ? $client_bd[2].'-'.$client_bd[1].'-'.$clie$
                            'client_passport_series'=>strlen($client_passport_series)<7 ? 1111111 : $client_passport_series,
                            'client_TIN'=>strlen($client_TIN)<8 ? 0 : (int) $client_TIN,
                    );
            }

            unset($csv_array[0]);

            return $this->flip($csv_array);
    }
```

Прошу помочь выявить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **move_uploaded_file**
>   Если filename не является загруженным файлом, никаких действий не
>   предпринимается и move_uploaded_file() возвращает FALSE.
>
> Если filename является загруженным файлом, но не может быть перемещён
>   по каким-либо причинам, никаких действий не предпринимается и
>   move_uploaded_file() возвращает FALSE.

скорее всего, не может переместить в указанный вами каталог. Возможно каталог не существует, возможно нет прав на запись. Если нет отладчика, то хотя бы допишите

```
echo 'Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер. Попробуйте еще раз. Имя конечного файла' . $targetFile;
```

Чтобы проверить, куда пишет